# How to rescue from a specific error (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rescue

I have a specific error I want to rescue from;

The error grabbed from the console is...

```
JSON::ParserError: 751: unexpected token at ''
```

---

```
begin
    #do stuff
rescue
    if error is <JSON::ParserError: 751: unexpected token at ''>
         #do stuff
         next
    end
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can catch different errors and do the same action on them or do different actions. The syntax is the following.

Imagine you want to do different actions for different errors:

```
begin
  # Do something
rescue JSON::ParseError
  # Do something when the error is ParseError
rescue JSON::NestingError, JSON::UnparserError
  # Do something when the error is NestingError or UnparserError
rescue JSON::JSONError => e
  # Do something when the error is JSONError
  # Use the error from this variable `e'
rescue # same as rescue StandardError
  # Do something on other errors
end
```

If you are going to place all the code in the function inside a `begin rescue end` block, then you can ommit the `begin end` words, so instead of writing:

```
def my_func
  begin
    # do someting
  rescue JSON::ParseError
    # handle error
  end
end
```

You may write

```
def my_func
  # do something
rescue JSON::ParseError
  # handle error
end
```

Remember to never rescue from `Exception`. I know my answer may be a little too broad for your question but I hope it helps you and other people in similar doubts.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass the name to rescue, like this:

```
begin
  # ...
rescue JSON::ParserError
  # ...
end
```

If you want to pass multiple error classes to rescue, you can do so separating them with commas